# ChromeWebDriver - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to test my application on Chrome with ChromeWebDriver but every time I try I get following exception:

```
   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.46 seconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'PADAMSKI-W', ip: '10.10.8.60', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_37'
Driver info: pl.axit.test.selenium.env.KoralinaChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startSession(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:149)
```

In chromedriver.log I see

```
[0.681][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Users\padamski.AXIT.PL\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-update --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="C:\Users\PADAMS~1.PL\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4048_12236\internal" --logging-level=1 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12573 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\PADAMS~1.PL\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4048_22909" --window-size=6000,6000 data:,
[60.836][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
```

I'm using:

- Chrome 36
- ChromeWebDriver 2.10
- Windows 7

In Process Explorer I can see that chromedriver.exe process is running but no window is opened and after few seconds I get above exception.

My starting code is:

```
 File f = ResourceProvider.getResource("tools/win/chromedriver.exe");
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", f.getAbsolutePath());
 return new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: please, provide a code that is responsible for Chrome instance launch.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is good that WebDriver looks for Chrome in my AppData directory. When I tried to execute it by myself it also crashed. But when I run Chrome from "Program Files x86" directory then it starts normally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eventually I found out that WebDriver was trying to run Chrome from `C:\Users\______\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`, which was not working even when trying it manually. It was very strange because when I launch Chrome I use one installed in `Program Files` directory and it works without problems.

So I had uninstalled Chrome, deleted everything from `c:\Users______\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\` and installed Chrome again. After that it started working.

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well after following the setup instructions on the Selenium GitHub page, which mentions that the Chrome executable is expected to be at the path you mentioned. All I needed to do to fix things was to delete the Application folder and everything in it. No reinstallation of Chrome necessary.

Comment: Use chrome proxy version as setBinary() and "options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");"

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as above. and I solved it.
I run selenium with chromium in alpine.
My environment:

- Alpine (Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)
- Chromium 53.0.2785.92
- chromedriver=2.22
- selenium (3.0.1)

and I met the error information is：

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:    Chrome failed to start: crashed
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.22 (5e2d5494d735a71aa5c2e7ef9bf5ce96945e92e9),platform=Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)
```

My solution is run:

```
apk add libexif udev
```

and Then it works.

I refer to here : https://hub.docker.com/r/rodrigomiguele/chromium/~/dockerfile/

Comment: If your organization has admin restrictions then you may want to check and use the chrome proxy version if it's provided; and use the "options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");"

Answer (score 3):

```
  DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");
        capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
        capability.setPlatform(PlatformAndEnvironmentSetUp.platformSetUp);

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + PlatformAndEnvironmentSetUp.hubIP + ":" + PlatformAndEnvironmentSetUp.hubPort + "/wd/hub"), capability);


        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
//page instances init()

        loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, LoginPage.class);
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, AdminHomePage.class);
```

This  sample code works OK for me.
Just a little note: "chromedriver.exe" I'm placing in the same project folder. That makes the question of path to chromdriver executable easier.

So this line of code looks in this way:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```

Resource to [download chromedriver.exe](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't helps - Chrome is still not starting.

Comment: Eventually I found out that is something with my Chrome. I have installed it, deleted everything from c:\Users\______L\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\  and installed Chrome again. After that it started working.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall, delete chrome profile from c:\Users______L\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\ and reinstall chrome will fix the problem, it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this on Windows 10 by setting chromedriver.exe, [yourPythonIDE].exe, and chrome.exe to run with Administrator rights, which can reached via right-clicking the exe file and going to Properties >> Compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue on Windows 10 by using the Administrator CMD to run my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as above. Turned out I somehow managed to have two chrome.exe installed. One under Program Files and on under user\appdata\local..... I uninstall the one under Program Files and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to start your browser in selenium. please ensure whether you set chrome browser as defualt? bcz of this also u may face this "Failed to start your browser" ERROR

Answer (score 0):

My browser can be opened, but it will report an error. After setting Google Chrome as the default browser, the error will not be reported again.

Answer (score -1):

im pretty sure looking at your error that your bindings for chrome may not be right - please try removing all your references to chrome and removing it from your project. then, if you havent already, install Nuget Packet Manager and download chrome webdriver from there - note there are 2 one by chromium and one from selenium.

hope this helps - let me know and if not ill take a closer look at it.

Comment: Eventually I found out that is was something with my Chrome. I had uninstalled it, deleted everything from c:\Users\______\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\ and installed Chrome again. After that it started working. Anyway thanks for your advice.

Comment: sorry, didnt realise how long ago this was, basically its down to your driver refrenecing the wrong version, messing up bindings - i had this error before too the only current work around was as you did to clear the entire pc of all its references to it, uninstall it completely then reinstall it, basically updating or just removing and reinstalling it wouldnt work its a slight issue i think with VS and the drivers bindings but yeah glad you fixed it - i only answered cause i knew the problem and its solution having encountered it myself haha :)

think my answer deserved an upvote though haha