# Automate SSO authentication in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I'm writing a Selenium script in Java. I've a website say `originalwebsite.com`, and when enter this and hit a go, it will go to `authenticationwebsite.com`, authenticate the credentials and auto redirect to `originalwebsite.com`.

I'm sorry that I can't reveal the `origianlwebsite` and `authenticationwebsite` URLs sine these are our Organisation's.

When I enter it directly in any Chrome browser, this is done automatically, since the `authenticationwebsite` credentials are stored.

But when i do it through Selenium, instead of redirecting to `originalwebsite.com`, the process stops at `authenticationwebsite.com` and asks for credentials. Going through some forums in `SO`, I've tried the below code.

**In Chrome**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
        // System.out.println(user);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments(
                "user-data-dir=C:/Users/" + user.toUpperCase() + "/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver cd = new ChromeDriver(options);
        cd.get("https://originalwebsite.com");
```

When I run this i get the below Exception.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1) on port 9702
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.39 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.1', revision: 'd80083d', time: '2015-10-08 21:07:25'
System info: host: 'U0138039-TPD-A', ip: '10.112.78.15', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
    at EaselTest.main(EaselTest.java:21)
```

But in Firefox, this is working fine. And the code that i've used is as below.

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
WebDriver cd = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
cd.get("https://originalwebsite.com");
```

Please let me know how can i do it in Chrome, since most of the users here use chrome as their default browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like selenium is failing to pick up chrome browser where it is installed.

Check this answer : [ChromeWebDriver - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311593/chromewebdriver-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-crashed)