# unknown error: chrome failed to start

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been stuck for days because of this issue and can't seem to find a solution. I can't get the chromedriver to work on my machine, no matter what I do. I've tried pretty much every setup I could possibly imagine. To list a few:

- Chrome 64 bits, Python 64 bits
- Chrome 32 bits, Python 32 bits
- Chrome 64 bits, Python 32 bits
- Chrome 32 bits, Python 64 bits

I've also tried different versions of Chrome with their corresponding chromedriver versions. I've tried different prior versions of selenium, and that is, on every previously mentioned setups.

For an actual context, here's my current setup:

- Windows 10 Professional x64
- Python 3.6.3 64 bits
- Selenium 3.7.0
- Google Chrome 62.0.3202.75 64 bits
- Chromedriver 2.33

I will not post my code as no matter which code I use, it fails. Even the simplest most basic code that launches a chromedriver will not work. Also, it works on my colleague's machine. So to give some context, here's a code snippet I've tried that doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="bin/chromedriver.exe")
```

I've also tried to add the chromedriver to my `PATH` and launching the chromedriver with no arguments but this doesn't work either.

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

And here's the log that gets generated if I launch the driver with the verbose/logging parameters:

```
[1.979][INFO]: COMMAND InitSession {
   "capabilities": {
      "alwaysMatch": {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "args": [  ],
            "extensions": [  ]
         },
         "platformName": "any"
      },
      "firstMatch": [ {

      } ]
   },
   "desiredCapabilities": {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
         "args": [  ],
         "extensions": [  ]
      },
      "platform": "ANY",
      "version": ""
   }
}
[1.985][INFO]: Populating Preferences file: {
   "alternate_error_pages": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "autofill": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "browser": {
      "check_default_browser": false
   },
   "distribution": {
      "import_bookmarks": false,
      "import_history": false,
      "import_search_engine": false,
      "make_chrome_default_for_user": false,
      "show_welcome_page": false,
      "skip_first_run_ui": true
   },
   "dns_prefetching": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "profile": {
      "content_settings": {
         "pattern_pairs": {
            "https://*,*": {
               "media-stream": {
                  "audio": "Default",
                  "video": "Default"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "default_content_setting_values": {
         "geolocation": 1
      },
      "default_content_settings": {
         "geolocation": 1,
         "mouselock": 1,
         "notifications": 1,
         "popups": 1,
         "ppapi-broker": 1
      },
      "password_manager_enabled": false
   },
   "safebrowsing": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "search": {
      "suggest_enabled": false
   },
   "translate": {
      "enabled": false
   }
}
[1.989][INFO]: Populating Local State file: {
   "background_mode": {
      "enabled": false
   },
   "ssl": {
      "rev_checking": {
         "enabled": false
      }
   }
}
[2.004][INFO]: Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted incorrectly
[2.004][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-browser-side-navigation --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="C:\Users\OLIVIE~1.VER\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9668_31484\internal" --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12606 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\OLIVIE~1.VER\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9668_609" data:,
[2.035][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: chrome failed to start
[2.035][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[2.035][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

I've had a look at pretty much every similar questions I could find, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311593/8332700), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36133894/8332700) for example, and none of the solutions I've came across helped, it's always the same error I get. I've been having the same error with the dozen of different setups I've tried.

A few months ago I remember I successfully ran the chromedriver for another project on the same machine.

I think I've provided all the necessary information, but don't hesitate to ask me in comments if I forgot something.

Thanks

Comment: What's the selenium version?

Comment: @DavidePatti latest from a fresh `pip install`, so that would be `selenium 3.7.0`. I admit I didn't think about trying other versions of selenium yet.

Comment: Alright, I tried selenium `3.6.0` and `3.5.0` and it's still the same error every time.

Comment: In the error it states that it's launching `chrome.exe` and not `chromedriver.exe`... is that normal? I would have expected `chromedriver.exe`. Are you sure your path to the exe is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going through an endless amount of different solutions with no results, but what seemed to really fix it in the end was the following:

- Uninstall Chrome
- Go through Windows Registry and delete every keys named `{8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96}`
- Reinstall Chrome

I ended up getting to this solution after following the solution from [DebanjanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150467/8332700) and couldn't install Chrome anymore. Searching about this new issue led me to find [this post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/pyZ6W4cqFoM/qNTgAdEjBTMJ).

*`Remember to backup your registry before doing this.`*

After doing this I was able to reinstall Chrome and run the chromedriver.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all **`Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted incorrectly`**. This error have introduced some more errors as:

```
[2.035][INFO]: RESPONSE InitSession unknown error: chrome failed to start
[2.035][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[2.035][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

So basically this error is not of `Selenium` or `Chrome` as such.

Here are the 3 best possible [**solutions**](https://github.com/atom/atom-keymap/issues/37) [*to your*](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/3hii4fN6w7A/o1-rDc-OskgJ) [`problem`](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2760779/windows-wrong-keys.html).

---

### Update :

As you have got rid of the error `Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted incorrectly` but you still see **`WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: chrome failed to start`** follow the steps as below :

1. Uninstall **`Chrome`** through **`Revo Uninstaller`** with `Moderate Memory Scan` so that the unwanted registry entries are cleared.
2. Run **`CCleaner`** tool before and after executing your `Tests` to wipe off all the OS chores.
3. **`Reboot`** your system.
4. **`Execute`** your `Test` as:

   ```
   driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
   ```

Comment: I've tried and now I no longer get the `Cannot switch to US keyboard layout - some keys may be interpreted incorrectly` error in the output log but, other than this line being gone, the log is exactly the same, and the error when launching chromedriver remains the same as well.

Comment: Also I'm not really sure how the keyboard layout would prevent the driver from launching at all like this.

Comment: Well, after doing this I can't even install Chrome anymore. The installer throws an error saying I already have Chrome installed on this machine and that I should uninstall it first, yet I can't find the slightest trace of it on my machine.... great

Comment: @Verv That's great !!! So now we have found out the core issue. Let's solve this for once & for ever.

Comment: @Verv Did you take help of Revo Uninstaller & CCleaner before taking the Reboot?

Comment: Yes. After the reboot I tried to install Chrome and got this error.

Comment: @Verv I suppose it's the undeleted Registry Key which is creating all the chaos. Try to search for registry entries with the word `chrome` and delete all those entries. But these leftovers should have been caught either by Revo or CCleaner I suppose.

Comment: I've deleted everything I could find that had either Google or Chrome in it's name and still have the same issue...

Comment: @Verv Keep Team Viewer v12.0 installed on your system. Tomorrow morning my time share your PC let me see if I can pull out something. As a last attempt try to clean the registry with CCleaner.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Your answer wasn't the full solution but it still ended up leading me to the actual solution (see my posted answer). Have a +1, thanks.