# WebDriver Error: chrome exited abnormally

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a python scraper (for webpages and PDFs) on a remote machine. I login to the remote machine to check back in at odd intervals, and the code usually breaks with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 148, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543619 (a237acd3116cac3b3f0da42a000502ce3fafcb23),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64)
```

Currently running `selenium` 3.9, `chromedriver` 2.37, and `chrome` 64. Have tried with chrome 65, and various chromedrivers, but still this error ultimately occurs.

Running this on `screen` so I can log out of the machine, but also running `pyvirtualdisplay` and `chrome` as headless. Would any of those conflict to draw the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unknown error: chrome failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142311/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start)

Comment: @DebanjanB, I'm trying this now. To let you know, this is scraping pdfs for 1500 orgs, so it crawls through about ~80 pages per org to retrieve links for ~1000 pdfs per org. Are too many resources being consumed, which is why `chrome failed to start`?

Comment: Before you kick start ensure all your binaries are the current one e.g Selenium 3.11.0, ChromeDriver 2.37 & Chrome 65.x. You should be through.

Comment: @DebanjanB running chromedriver 2.37, chrome 65.x, and selenium [3.9 for python](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). Is this why I'm having this issue?

Comment: @debanjanb script broke again. After 10 hours. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Same error? Update the question with the error stack trace please.