# WebDriverError: unknown error: chrome failed to start.(Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Tags: protractor

**My Configuration:**

- npm: 3.10.0
- protractor: 4.10.3
- Chrome: 55
- chromedriver Version: chromedriver_2.25

Unable to execute any file in protractor.

**Command prompt status:**

```
C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriv
er-manager\selenium\report\report>protractor conf.js
Report destination:   C:\Users\rmomin\report\report\screenshots\my-report.html
(node:3580) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() inste
ad.
[11:55:57] I/launcher - Running 3 instances of WebDriver
[11:56:01] I/testLogger -
------------------------------------

[11:56:01] I/testLogger - [chrome #01-2] PID: 8956
[chrome #01-2] Specs: C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\report\report\02-discussions.js
[chrome #01-2]
[chrome #01-2] (node:8956) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os
.tmpdir() instead.
[chrome #01-2] [11:55:57] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[chrome #01-2] [11:55:59] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http:/
/10.165.6.34:38852/wd/hub
[chrome #01-2]
[chrome #01-2] C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639
[chrome #01-2]         throw new ctor(message);
[chrome #01-2]               ^
[chrome #01-2] WebDriverError: unknown error: chrome failed to start
[chrome #01-2]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09
729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server
 did not provide any stacktrace information)
[chrome #01-2] Command duration or timeout: 723 milliseconds
[chrome #01-2] Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-0
6-30 17:37:03'
[chrome #01-2] System info: host: 'rmomin-PC', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Win
dows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
[chrome #01-2] Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[chrome #01-2]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:639:1
5)
[chrome #01-2]     at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:538:13)
[chrome #01-2]     at client_.send.then.response (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:472:
11)
[chrome #01-2]     at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js
:1379:14)
[chrome #01-2]     at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
[chrome #01-2]     at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21
)
[chrome #01-2]     at asyncRun (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
[chrome #01-2]     at C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
[chrome #01-2]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7
)
[chrome #01-2] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[chrome #01-2]     at Function.createSession (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:329:2
4)
[chrome #01-2]     at Builder.build (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\builder.js:458:24)
[chrome #01-2]     at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData
\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\driverProvider.js:37:
33)
[chrome #01-2]     at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:198:43)
[chrome #01-2]     at C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\built\runner.js:277:30
[chrome #01-2]     at _fulfilled (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
[chrome #01-2]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
[chrome #01-2]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
[chrome #01-2]     at C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
[chrome #01-2]     at runSingle (C:\Users\rmomin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)

[11:56:01] I/testLogger -

[11:56:01] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[11:56:01] I/launcher - 2 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:56:01] I/testLogger -

[11:56:01] I/testLogger -

[11:56:01] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[11:56:01] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:56:01] I/launcher - chrome #01-2 failed with exit code: 1
[11:56:01] I/launcher - chrome #01-1 failed with exit code: 1
[11:56:01] I/launcher - chrome #01-0 failed with exit code: 1
[11:56:01] I/launcher - overall: 3 process(es) failed to complete
Closing report
[11:56:01] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Comment: The `os.tmpDir` is just a warning. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: You may want to check [ChromeWebDriver - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311593/chromewebdriver-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-crashed). Protractor might look for Chrome in a folder where it is not?

Comment: @ cnishina: 55.0.2883.87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed for me now what I did:

1. download chrome.exe file and selenium jar file and keep the both files in `C:..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`
2. Now run in command prompt `..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium> webdriver-manager update`
3. then run `webdriver-manager start`
4. then run you configuration file