# Chrome crashes after launching [Selenium] [Python]

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a small script to load my default Chrome profile and open a site using Selenium. However, after chrome successfully launches, the code pauses for a while and then crashes.

**My script:**

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\hbur3\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") 
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized");
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    wd.get("https://google.com.au/")
```

**Python error:**

```
  selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

**Chromedriver log:**

```
[2.638][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-infobars --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --load-component-extension="C:\Users\hbur3\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir21208_8173\internal" --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=12638 --safebrowsing-disable-auto-update --start-maximized --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir="C:\Users\hbur3\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
    [2.641][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12638/json/version
    [4.644][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
    [4.695][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12638/json/version
    [4.896][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
    [4.946][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12638/json/version
    [6.699][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
    [6.750][DEBUG]: DevTools request: http://localhost:12638/json/version
    [6.950][DEBUG]: DevTools request failed
        etc...
```

I have tried a whole range of solutions, including:

- Reinstalling Chromedriver
- Creating a new Chrome user profile
- Copying the default profile elsewhere
- Only running when no other Chrome windows were open

I'm loathed to delete my profile and reinstall Chrome, but this may be my only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to do what you're afraid of... see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282429/2470092). you can [export](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/export-chrome-profile-79321.html) and import your profile to save time.

Another thing you can try is to start a `RemoteWebDriver` instead of `ChromeDriver`. First run the `chromedriver.exe`, then connect to it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
command_executor='http://localhost:9515/',
desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

If your problem still reporduces, look for an open [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list) or perhaps open a new one.