# no such session exception while Loading Default/Custom Chrome Profile to run tests using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am loading custom profile of chrome by using following code:

```
ChromeDriverService chSvc = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("C://Users//kanu//Downloads//Selenium//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe")).usingAnyFreePort().build(); 
            ChromeOptions chOption = new ChromeOptions();
            /**
             * "user-data-dir = profilepath" --to open profile
             * "--start-maximized" for maximize the browser 
             */
            chOption.addArguments("user-data-dir = C:/Users/kanu/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/New User");
            chOption.addArguments("--start-maximized");        
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chSvc, chOption);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

it works and run the existing profile of chrome but is not opening the desired url and getting following exception :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9)         on port 43388
   Only local connections are allowed.
   Mar 15, 2017 10:55:27 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake                    createSession
   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no        such session
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174        (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586        x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   Command duration or timeout: 8 milliseconds
   Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10        09:04:52 -0800'
   System info: host: 'GUR-ACC093-W', ip: '100.102.83.217', os.name:                      'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
   Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174        (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586        x86_64), platform=ANY}]
   Session ID: ea04006993fa5bd7530cfe75cca7ae0d
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:638)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
at launch.LaunchChrome.main(LaunchChrome.java:50)
```

Can anyone please resolve this?

Comment: Check your chrome driver version and google chrome version.

Comment: Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit), chrome driver version is 2.39

Comment: In exception it is showing `chromedriver=2.27.440174` . And try with chromedriver version 2.38

Comment: Download the latest chrome driver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311593/chromewebdriver-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-crashed)

Comment: after using 2.38, the chrome is not even opening up

Comment: I found one thing in my case, while using custom profile for chrome. Uncheck "Let google chrome run in background" from Desktop Task bar and it stopped from crashing.